# sql using select and adding to a table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT `pro`.`St`, `s`.`Quantity`
    FROM `s`
    LEFT JOIN `web`.`pro` ON `s`.`Pro_id` = `pro`.`ProdID`
```

the above query results in a table like

```
    st          quantity
    132             1
    11              1
```

st is from one table and quantity is from another 
using this select statement I want to add the resulting quantity to the st row in the other table.

Basically updating the second table by adding the quantity i get from this select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `web`.`pro`
SET `pro`.`st` = `pro`.`st` + `s`.`Quantity`
FROM `web`.`pro`
JOIN `shopping cart` `s`
  ON `s`.`Pro_id` = `pro`.`ProdID`;
```

Something like that ?

Comment: i updated it a bit because i changed my table name using this produces an error on join now

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `web`.`pro` JOIN `s' ON `st`.`Pro_id` = `pro' at line 3